# onclick on hyperlink should add a div horizontally using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

My html:

```
<div id="contentDiv"> 
    <div id="headerDiv" ><div id="titleDiv"> Queries</div></div>
    <div id="valuesDiv" ><div id="yearDiv"> 2015</div></div>
    <div id="graphDiv" ><div id="chartDiv">graph</div></div>
</div>
```

Like this div, I have another div but the content in the div is different.

How to add a new div horizontally when I click on hyperlink using angularjs?

How can I do this? please help me out regarding this

Comment: Can you show the working demo to get the correct understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you need is a two way binding with the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04). So the idea would be that you bind the new div to a variable in your scope which is initially in an empty or undefined state (for example, there are better ways). When the hyperlink is clicked it calls the function specified by an ng-click directive which will fill your bound object, which in turn will cause the new div to be rendered.

EDIT:
Based on your comments here is a simple example.

HTML page:

```
<div id="newDiv" ng-repeat="item in items">
 <!-- Div content -->
 <!-- example -->
 <input type="text" ng-model="item.name">
 </div>

 <input type="button" ng-click="addItem()">
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.items=[];
 $scope.addItem = function() {
    var newItem = {};
    newItem.name = "new item name";
    $scope.items.push(newItem);
 }
```

What's happening here is the data for each div is stored in an array of objects. The ng-repeat directive will repeat the div for each object in the array. You can then fill the elements in the div using the object. Adding a new div is as simple as adding a new item to the array and angular will take care of the rest for you. Please note that I have not tested this example, but hopefully it's enough to point you in the right direction.

RE aligning the divs horizontally, this will be done with CSS, using the inline-block display mode. So you could give the div a class of, for example, "horizontalDiv" and add the following class to your CSS file:

```
.horizontalDiv {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: ok.Can u please edit the code when u get an angular environment

Comment: like this I have 2 more divs.For the first Onclick of an add button, should display a 1st div and for the second Onclick of an add button,should display a 2nd div and so on.How can I do this ?

Comment: ok, are all the divs the same, just with different data? Or is each div different?

Comment: all the divs are same but each div has different data and I should align all the divs horizontally

Comment: k sure.Waiting for ur reply

Comment: How to add divs into an array?

Comment: You don't actually add any divs into the array. The array is filled with objects that contain the data you need for the divs. When you add a new object to the array angular will automatically add a new div. All you need is a function in your controller that fills an object and adds it to the array when the hyperlink is clicked. I've updated the code example above to hopefully make it a little clearer

Comment: I have same divs with different data.Can u please show this code in plunker

Comment: Ok, I put this in plunker. There were a few typos above, but the version in plunker works: https://plnkr.co/edit/bUUt0URGSFaafvgZxh3P?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help ewanc.  newItem.name = "new item name".Here in this string,can we place the div which I had mentioned above.

Comment: No, you don't want to be adding divs to anything. The ng-repeat directive will deal with this for you. All you need to do is fill the "item" object with the data you need and then in the div map the data to a field. I added a few more fields to the plunker example to demonstrate a bit better. But basically, all the data comes from your javascript, just put it all in an object and add to the array, angular does the actual adding of the div.

Comment: when I'm trying to create a second object and added the object to an array,the data is getting overrided.For each click,I want the description to be changed for every object

Comment: Hi, yeah I'll be happy to help out. These comments are getting very long though, so please put it in a new question with examples of the code that is causing you trouble.

Comment: please refer the url :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196200/onclick-of-a-button-should-display-the-divs-side-by-side-in-angularjs .I need to change the content of the div for every click