# Onclick of a button should display the divs side by side in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Onclick of a button,I'm trying to display the div's side by side.I have title,value and graph sections  with in a div.

I have these values in the form of a json.I'm unable to bind the data from script to the html page.Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

This data is different for different divs.How can I change the data in the div when I click on a button.

Comment: i can not see your `addItem` in html. what problem you are facing? your current code should work

Comment: I had edited my code.Please refer this url https://plnkr.co/edit/bUUt0URGSFaafvgZxh3P?p=preview .Here the description is same for all the divs.But I have different data for different divs.

Comment: If I am not wrong, in plnkr, the things are working fine as per your expectation. If not can you please clarify the problem..

Comment: Is it the data you're missing? You need to pass data from the dom to your newItem. For example by using ng-model directive on your input:

https://plnkr.co/edit/VxHAEJiQxvvMCgL5Uj4O?p=preview

Comment: So what you have there will add a new div whenever the button is clicked, but the data is hardcoded in the addItem() function so this needs to be modified to fill the js object with the data you need. Where is your data for the div stored?

Comment: I had edited the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the objects filled with the data you need, you just need to add them to the array for display. To do this you will need to keep track of which object you want to add. So you could keep a counter that you increment each time you add an item, then you can use this counter to select the object to add.

An easy way to make this work would be for all your items (not just the ones to display) to be stored in a separate array. Then you can add the items to display by changing your addItem() function to something like this:

```
var counter = 0;

 $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.items.push($scope.allItems[counter]);
    counter++;
 };
```

Comment: can u please refer this url :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238196/how-to-draw-a-d3-js-timeseries-graph-from-json-using-angular-directives and please help me out

Answer (score -1):

You are having `button` inside `ng-repeat`. Firstly their where `Zero` items. Put `button` outside it and works as you expected.

Put your objects in `Array` and then check for item occurrence.

```
$scope.count=0;

  $scope.items = [];
  var json = [
  {
"title" : " claim Queries1",
"prevyear" : "2014",
"currentyear" : "2015",
"prevtrend": "300",
"currenttrend" : "500",
"graph" : "graph1"
  },
 {
"title" : " claim Queries2",
"prevyear" : "2014",
"currentyear" : "2015",
"prevtrend" : "300",
"currenttrend" : "500",
"graph" : "graph2"
  },
  {
"title" : " claim Queries3",
"prevyear" : "2014",
"currentyear" : "2015",
"prevtrend" : "300",
"currenttrend" : "500",
"graph" : "graph3"
  }];

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    if($scope.count!=json.length)
    $scope.items.push(json[$scope.count]);  
    $scope.count++;
  };

});
```

**Run below Snippet**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 
  $scope.count=0;
  
  $scope.items = [];
  var json = [
  {
"title" : " claim Queries1",
"prevyear" : "2014",
"currentyear" : "2015",
"prevtrend": "300",
"currenttrend" : "500",
"graph" : "graph1"
  },
 {
"title" : " claim Queries2",
"prevyear" : "2014",
"currentyear" : "2015",
"prevtrend" : "300",
"currenttrend" : "500",
"graph" : "graph2"
  },
  {
"title" : " claim Queries3",
"prevyear" : "2014",
"currentyear" : "2015",
"prevtrend" : "300",
"currenttrend" : "500",
"graph" : "graph3"
  }];

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    if($scope.count!=json.length)
    $scope.items.push(json[$scope.count]);  
    $scope.count++;
  };

});
```

```css
#headerDiv,
#headerDiv2,
#headerDiv3,
#headerDiv4 {
  background-color: #0095ce;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#valuesDiv,
#valuesDiv2,
#valuesDiv3,
#valuesDiv4 {
  background-color: #00acec;
  height: 105px;
  text-align: center;
}
#graphDiv,
#graphDiv2,
#graphDiv3,
#graphDiv4 {
  background-color: #30c1fc;
  height: 105px;
  text-align: center;
}
#contentDiv,
#secondDiv,
#thirdDiv,
#fourthDiv {
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  position: relative
}
#titleDiv {
  width: 116px;
  top: 26px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 16pt;
}
#prevyearDiv {
  width: 116px;
  left: 65px;
  top: 31px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 14pt;
}
#currentyearDiv {
  width: 116px;
  left: 207px;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 14pt;
}
#prevtrendsDiv {
  width: 116px;
  top: 37px;
  left: 65px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 24pt;
}
#currenttrendsDiv {
  width: 116px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 205px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 24pt;
}
#chartDiv {
  width: 116px;
  top: 49px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 14pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl" style="height:100%;width:100%">

  <div id="contentDiv" ng-repeat="item in items" style="display: inline-block">
    <div id="headerDiv">
      <div id="titleDiv">{{item.name}}</div>
    </div>
    <div id="valuesDiv">
      <div id="prevyearDiv">{{item.value}}</div>
      <div id="currentyearDiv">{{item.value}}</div>
      <div id="prevtrendsDiv">{{item.desceiption}}</div>

      <div id="currenttrendsDiv">{{item.description}}</div>
    </div>
    <div id="graphDiv">
      <div id="chartDiv">{{item.graph}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>      
  <input type="button" ng-click="addItem()" value="add" style="display: block">
</div>
```

Comment: @dev777 check my answer

Comment: Actually I have the different data for different divs as mentioned above.I want to display the different data on different div when onclick

Comment: @dev777 do push data on `addItem` from where this data is coming from? API or from a `form`?

Comment: I tried pushing the code,but last data is getting overrided and that data is displaying in all the div's.Can u please edit the code over here

Comment: you are having static data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102570/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-dev777).

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help